# Spring security with filters only for specific url

Tags: spring, security, jwt

I want security to trigger only for specific URLs with a key in them, what I think is happening is that I bypass spring security, but the added Authorization filter that extends the BasicAuthenticationFilter is triggering with every url how can I set urls to the added BasicAuthenticationFilter also. I am implementing Jwt token.

This is my config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userService;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("**/auth/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(authenticationFilter())
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);


        http.headers().cacheControl();
    }
    public AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception{
        final AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter  = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
        authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");
        return authenticationFilter ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Options**

1. Extend `BasicAuthenticationFilter` and as a consequence of inheritance you can write your own authentication approach, during run time methods from sub-class will be taken into account from Spring security side.
2. Extend `AbstractAuthenticationFilter` and do required filtering there.